# Kubernetes keeps re-pulling images

Tags: docker, image, kubernetes, microk8s

Using `microk8s` installation. An image is tagged, so should use `IfNotPresent` policy.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
  2 kind: Deployment
  3 metadata:
  4   name: lh-graphql
  5   labels:
  6     app: lh-graphql 
  7 spec:
  8   selector:
  9     matchLabels:
 10       app: lh-graphql
 11   strategy:
 12     type: Recreate
 13   template:
 14     metadata:
 15       labels:
 16         app: lh-graphql
 17     spec:
 18       containers:
 19       - image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.13.2.cli-migrations-v3 
 20         name: lh-graphql 
 21         ports:
 22         - containerPort: 8080
 23           name: lh-graphql        
 24         env:
 25         - name: HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL  
 26           value: postgresql://postgres:postgres@$(ORCH_POSTGRES_IP):5432/lh
```

Image is already pulled to docker:

```
light@siddhalok:~$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                                   TAG                         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
postgres                                                     12                          3d6880d04326   2 weeks ago    373MB
hasura/graphql-engine                                        v2.13.2.cli-migrations-v3   4cd490369623   2 months ago   570MB
```

However, it keeps pulling after a deployment is deleted and created again.

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  112s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/lh-graphql-6db75544cf-j65wp to siddhalok
  Normal  Pulling    112s  kubelet            Pulling image "hasura/graphql-engine:v2.13.2.cli-migrations-v3"
```

**UPD:**

The same happens when creating from command line:

```
microk8s kubectl run det2 --image=registry.dev.mpksoft.ru/lighthouse/lh-detector/lh-detector:current --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
```

```
REPOSITORY                                                   TAG                         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
postgres                                                     12                          3d6880d04326   2 weeks ago    373MB
lh-develop.img                                               latest                      f26c3c667fbe   5 weeks ago    2.82GB
dpage/pgadmin4                                               latest                      4d5afde0a02e   6 weeks ago    361MB
detector                                                     latest                      e6f7e6567b73   7 weeks ago    3.81GB
lh-detetctor.img                                             latest                      e6f7e6567b73   7 weeks ago    3.81GB
registry.dev.mpksoft.ru/lighthouse/lh-detector/lh-detector   current                     e6f7e6567b73   7 weeks ago    3.81GB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the **microK8s** and Docker still it's necessary **microk8s** to have an idea about the docker that is running on your machine. local Docker daemon is not part of the **MicroK8s** Kubernetes cluster.

You can **export** the image and inject to **cache**

```
docker save <image name> > myimage.tar
microk8s ctr image import myimage.tar
```

Ref : [doc](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-images)

Comment: Thanks, read the doc.  What you mean by "microk8s to have an idea about the docker"? We can tell him to use the local docker installation as `conainerd`?

Comment: you can update the value of kubelet config and chance container runtime to docker instead contained.